# window.location.href and window.open () methods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, location, window, href, window-object

What is the difference between `window.location.href` and `window.open ()` methods in JavaScript?

Comment: Related: [How do I redirect to another webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Answer (score 636, accepted):

`window.location.href` is **not** a method, it's a property that will tell you the current URL location of the browser. Changing the value of the property will redirect the page.

`window.open()` is a method that you can pass a URL to that you want to open in a new window. For example:

**window.location.href example:**

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; //Will take you to Google.
```

**window.open() example:**

```
window.open('http://www.google.com'); //This will open Google in a new window.
```

---

Additional Information:

`window.open()` can be passed additional parameters. See: [window.open tutorial](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)

Comment: The standard probably does say that `window.location.href` is a property, not a method, but Internet Explorer (version 10 at least) allows you to treat `href` as a method too. I've seen it work, only in IE10, on one page I've used. That's probably why the asker was calling `href` a method. See the question [IE incompatability with window.location.href](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10201809/578288). But yes, it's better to use `href` as a property, which will work in any browser, [including IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533867%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @RoryO'Kane, this question was asked in 2011. I doubt the user was referring to IE 10.

Comment: True. But I think it’s likely, though not certain, that older versions of IE treated `window.location.href` the same way. After all, newer versions of iE are generally getting *more* standards-based, not less. So if IE10 is still breaking the standard, then older versions probably did too.

Comment: What's the difference between using `window.open(newUrl, '_self')` and location.href = newUrl` ? Both will open the `newUrl` in the same tab.

Answer (score 34):

- `window.open` will open a new browser with the specified URL.
- `window.location.href` will open the URL in the window in which the code is called.

Note also that `window.open()` is a function on the window object itself whereas `window.location` is an object that exposes a variety of [other methods and properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.location).

Answer (score 17):

There are already answers which describes about [window.location.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) property and [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) method.

I will go by Objective use:

### 1. To redirect the page to another

Use window.location.href. Set href property to the href of another page.

### 2. Open link in the new or specific window.

Use window.open(). Pass parameters as per your goal.

### 3. Know current address of the page

Use window.location.href. Get value of window.location.href property. You can also get specific protocol, hostname, hashstring from window.location object.

See [Location Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) for more information.

Answer (score 15):

[window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) is a method; you can open new window, and can customize it.
window.location.href is just a property of the current window.

Answer (score 10):

`window.open ()` will open a new window, whereas `window.location.href` will open the new URL in your current window.

Comment: window.open() can also open the 'url' in the same window if   '_self' is passed as additional parameter.

Comment: yes, had the same doubt. What's the difference between using `window.open(newUrl, '_self')` and location.href = newUrl` ?

Answer (score 2):

The `window.open` will open url in new browser Tab

The `window.location.href` will open url in current Tab (instead you can use `location`)

Here is [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lamik/6unwzs90/) (in SO snippets window.open doesn't work)

```js
var url = 'https://example.com';

function go1() { window.open(url) }

function go2() { window.location.href = url }

function go3() { location = url }
```

```html
<div>Go by:</div>
<button onclick="go1()">window.open</button>
<button onclick="go2()">window.location.href</button>
<button onclick="go3()">location</button>
```