# IE incompatability with window.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm using a callback from an AJAX post request to navigate to a new page, but it is not working on Internet Explorer. My code is as follows:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: phpUrl,  
    data: data,  
    async: false, 
    success: function() {       
         if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'){   window.location.href("/step2.php")}
         else{ window.location.href = "/step2.php"}             
    },  
    dataType:'json'         

});
```

This works fine on FF/Safari/Chrome but when I test it on IE it does not work. Is there a better way of redirecting to a new page? I'm using `async:false` as my data was not loading on Chrome/Safari if I did not use a callback as the page would just change before the `POST` request was complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the parentheses.  `href` is not a function, so trying to invoke it—`window.location.href("/step2.php")`—is a `TypeError`.

Assign to `href` like you do on the next line, or better, use [`location.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location):

```
location.assign('/step2.php');
```

While you can directly assign to `location`'s properties (`location.href='...';`) to cause the browser to navigate, I recommend against this.

Internally, doing so is just calling `location.assign()` anyway, and assigning to properties [does not always behave the same in all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Examples).

---

Regarding, `async:false`, ***never* do that**.  If you make a synchronous XHR request, [**you're doing it wrong**](http://kellegous.com/ecrits/001096).  [8.4%](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/03/do-not-use-xmlhttprequest-in-synchronous-mode-unless-you-like-to-hang.aspx) of reported IE9 hangs were due to synchronous XHR blocking the browser.

Given that you have it in a callback, the assignment to `location` won't happen until the POST completes, so I'm not sure what you mean by "the page would change before the POST completes."  (Did you forget to cancel a form's `submit`?)

Comment: strange. `location.assign("/step2.php");` is not working on IE either, but does work on FF/Safari/Chrome. My original attempt at using it as a function was based on the documentation that I read (that @Hexxagonal referred to also).

Comment: I take your point about the `async` - I've removed it. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: _Never_ is a strong word. It is sometimes necessary and useful for synchronous ajax. However, your point is well taken. And in cases where blocking is necessary, developers should take care to visibly show that something is still happening, i.e. an ajax loader gif.

Comment: @peter: This is a case where I'm comfortable with the word *never*.    The point is that if you use synchronous XHR, you *can't* show a loader gif because the XHR request blocks your page from rendering.  I honestly think there's no situation where async XHR can't be used; and there are too many downsides to sync XHR to justify using it over async.

Comment: I used it in mix  with window.location.href...thought of it as a fallback for ie, and it made my issue go away. It redirects properly now, instead of fumbling through other scripts

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href = "/step2.php"` is just fine.

Comment: hmmm, it's fine on everything except IE! Do you have any thoughts on why it does not work on this browser?

Answer (score 0):

IE only like full url.

```
var fullURL = 'http://www.your_site.com/step2.php';

$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: phpUrl,  
    data: data,  
    async: false, 
    success: function() {

        window.location.href(fullURL);

    },  
    dataType:'json'         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

';

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: phpUrl,
data: data,
async: false,
success: function() {

```
    window.location.href(fullURL);

},  
dataType:'json'
```

});

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).