# I Can not open created PDF on new tab genered by PDFMake.js in Internet Exploer

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, pdf, window.location, pdfmake

I am working on a projected developed using WEB API2 and AngularJS. I am created report in PDF using pdfmake.js. It works fine for Firefox. But for security reason, I like to restrict the user to use Internet Explorer. Because I need to identify the user terminal using MAC Address.

So I commanded users to use Internet Explorer. In Internet explorer, When I want to open the PDF new tab, PDFMake.js getting error on following line:

```
Document.prototype.open = function(message) {
    // we have to open the window immediately and store the reference
    // otherwise popup blockers will stop us
    var win = window.open('', '_blank');

    try {
        this.getDataUrl(function(result) {
            win.location.href = result;
        });
    } catch(e) {
        win.close();
        throw e;
    }
};
```

The line `win.location.href = result;` generating error :

> Unhandled exception at line 110, column 8 in http://localhost:19884/Scripts/pdfmake/pdfmake.js
>   0x8007007a - JavaScript runtime error: unknown exception

[Image of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEHeQ.png)

I googled and didn't get any solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the things which can solve the issue -

1. Try using `window.location.href` instead.
2. Try using `document.location.href` instead

Also read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201809/ie-incompatability-with-window-location-href) for more