# Why my angular app send many request in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm working with my Angular application in Chrome and IE. Although in Chrome it runs very fast but in IE my Angular app is very slow.

I just debug my application in IE and Chrome and see IE send many requests but Chrome only sends 1.

In Chrome:

[image]

In IE:

[image]

This is code I implement this function:

```
vm.save = function () {
        // Logic here

        ConfigFactory.api.update({}, ConfigFactory.data[0], function (response) {
            vm.showSuccess = true;
            vm.oldConfigs = angular.copy(vm.configs);

            $timeout(function () {
                vm.showSuccess = false;
            }, 1000)

            $window.location.href = '#/Home';
        });
    }
```

---

UPDATED: After I do not clear when navigation in IE:

[image]

IE still send many requests.

This is the error log.

[image]

This log only appear in IE, Chrome have nothing

Comment: You don't just happen to have the IE equivalent of *"Preserve log"* on, do you?

Comment: ... I think it's called [*"Clear entries on navigate"*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/f12-devtools-guide/network)

Comment: can you show the error in the console for IE ?

Comment: @Phil I have update as your request. Help me check this.

Comment: @MrBones, I have update log. Can you help me check this. It only appear in IE. Chrome have nothing

Comment: Looks like some issue with how you rendered the content. check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116114/how-to-troubleshoot-angular-10-digest-iterations-reached-error) and see if it helps

Comment: Is there any chance that when you navigate to `#/Home`, the method `save` is fired again? So it will create infinite loop. Check this out it may relate to your issue: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201809/ie-incompatability-with-window-location-href`

Comment: There are chances your method is called repeatedly ..so it repeatedly try to redirect,hence multiple calls. Take a look at this you will understand -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116114/how-to-troubleshoot-angular-10-digest-iterations-reached-error

Comment: What version of IE is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can see, the problem is that your code is going into an infinite loop and reloading angular context over and over again. When you use $window.location you are reloading your application - why not to use routing system to avoid reloading? And if you need data saved, then store it in a service, and re-fetch it from that service from the home route controller.

Comment: et godt svar, hilsner maytham

Answer (score 1):

Don't use $window.location. here if you use routing concept i think you not facing the problem.

[See angular route details](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)