# Redirection of window.open() does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser, window.open

I have the following code which works perfectly in Chrome: by clicking on `New`, it opens a popup, then clicking on `Change` leads to the redirection to another page.

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/dipewopuko/1/edit?html,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="contentCtrl">
    <button ng-click="openNew()">New</button>
    <button ng-click="change()">Change</button>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
      app.controller('contentCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.openNew = function () {
          $scope.popup = window.open("https://www.stackoverflow.com", "popup", "status=1, location=1");
        }

        $scope.change = function () {
          // $scope.popup = window.open("https://www.sina.com", "popup", "status=1, location=1");
          // $scope.popup.location.assign("https://www.sina.com")
          // $scope.popup.location.href("https://www.sina.com")
          // $scope.popup.location = "https://www.sina.com"
          $scope.popup.location.href = "https://www.sina.com"
        }
      }]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, this code does not work in IE 11. I have found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201809/ie-incompatability-with-window-location-href) which lists several ways of redirection in IE, I tried `location.assign(...)`, `location.href(...)`, etc. none of them worked.

Does anyone know how to achieve the redirection of window.open in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535866(v=vs.85).aspx), `window.location.href=` seems to be the best way to set (and get) the URL of a window in IE.

If that's not working, replace should do the trick: `$scope.popup.location.replace("https://www.google.com/");`

Comment: Happy to hear ;)