# How to set a cookie with jQuery in a PHP function

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-cookie

I have a very basic validation script using PHP, and I want to set a cookie with jQuery Cookie plugin if they are validated. Being very new to PHP, I don't know how to code a Javascript function here:

```
if($validated) {
  //SET jQUERY COOKIE HERE: $.cookie('COOKIE_NAME', 'COOKIE_INFO', { expires: 1, path: '/' });)
  header("Location: correct.php");
} else {
  header("Location: incorrect.php");
}
```

I know I can use PHP for this, but later on I need to access the cookie in a jQuery function, and being far more familiar with client-side, I'd like it to be done using jQuery Cookie plugin.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you create it in php, JavaScript will be able to access it. There is no reason to do it with JavaScript in this context.

Comment: Did you know that setting Cookies is not a specific feature of jQuery? `jQuery.cookie` only provides a simple API for manipulating cookies at the client's side, it'll never becomer harder to read cookies using jQuery.cookie if the cookies are set on the server's side..

Comment: Didn't know jQuery could access server side cookies!

Comment: Oh... I'd suggest you to feel the difference between server side and client side first.

Comment: You will also want an exit or die after your header...

Comment: If you want to set/get local info with JavaScript/jQuery, localStorage and sessionStorage are much easier to work with than cookies, unless you have to be geriatric-browser compatible (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are mixing concepts.

You can set a cookie in both server and client sides. And this cookie can be read by both parts again.

So you can set the cookie with PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) and read it with jQuery (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Hope it helps. Regards.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know this could be done. This is why I love Stack Overflow, you learn new things everyday. Have now set it in PHP :)

Answer (score 1):

It could be done in JavaScript but there is no reason not to use PHP. The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) page is quite straightforward.

If you do implement it in JavaScript, simply break out into a regular page and include your script in the way you would usually. You'll need a [`window.location.href`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript) call in there to redirect after setting the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Please use google:
[PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Syntax:
`bool setcookie ( $name , $value , $expire , $path  );`