# Using PhoneGap external url but Cordora js not working in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, adt

I'm facing a problem when I create a program by PhoneGap.

in my program, I'm using a local index.html file in my main activity, after the index.html loaded, I'm using window.open to redirect my page to an external page from the other server.

```js
window.open("http://192.168.0.11/test.html", '_self');
```

now the page redirect to test.html, cordova.js was included in test.html:

```js
//included the cordova js file in test.html file
<script src="js/cordova.js"></script>
```

in test.html, I called the the "exitApp" method of cordora as following:

```js
function onExit()
{
    navigator.app.exitApp();
}
```

however, I saw the error message as following in ADT logcat:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'exitApp' of undefined

but this file is working when I call it by local e.g. file:///adnroid_asset/www/test.html

anyone can help me on this? thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a bug of cordova 2.7.0, I'm using 2.6.0 and it's working well right now, so I will close this question, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `window.open`. Basically it'll try to open it in a new window and you'll lose the reference to Cordova objects. Use:

```
window.location.href = "http://192.168.0.11/test.html"
```

Which will simply load the give url in the same page, keeping the Cordova objects.

More details on the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript).

Comment: sorry, it doesn't help, the error still there, here is my code:

Comment: I found that when I use this file in local, it's working well, but when I call it remotely, I saw there is an error say : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <:1