# Weird behavior on redirecting using javascript on MVC3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

I have a `select` like this:

```
<select id="Link" name="Link"><option value="">Link Websites</option>
<option value="www.google.com">test link</option>
</select>
```

I want to redirect to `www.google.com` when user select `test link` option. Here the js I used:

```
$("body").on("change", ".site > select", function () {
        if ($(this).selectedIndex != 0) {
            window.location.replace($(this).val());
        }        
    });
```

But instead of getting redirect to `www.google.com`, I got something like `localhost:8000/www.google.com`. Is this have anything to do with `URL filter` on MVC3? Or I'm missing something?

Comment: have you tried with `window.location.href()` instead of `window.location.replace()` ? have a look on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript)

Comment: use `window.location = $(this).val();`

Comment: I tried all those option, and still have the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide protocol in the option value for the url:

```
<option value="http://www.google.com">test link</option>
```

Otherwise it is treated as `pathname` (relative url) and appended to the current url.

See the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location)