# Routing to a page from JavaScript side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Currently I do something like this:

```
+    var go_to = "http://localhost:3000" + url; 
+    window.open(go_to);
```

Which takes it to the Index action of a Rail controller and eventually shows the page.

Two things I want to improve:
1- Definitely hard coding `"http://localhost:3000"` is dead wrong. But what is the right way?

2- Is there a better way of talking to Rails from JS side to open a new window?

Comment: Use `window.location` (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp): 1): You can use `window.location.hostname` to get the hostname. 2): I don't think there is better solution that `window.open(url)` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript)

Comment: Ok tried window.location.hostname , it gives me like "localhost" but notice I still have that port number there? Is there a way to totally autogenerate that hard coded part of "http://localhost:3000"

Comment: `window.location.hostname + ':' + window.location.port` should solve the problem of the port (don't add it if equal to 80). I don't think there is a way to autogenerate the url. But the URL you are describing looks like the development mode. You could try something like (sorry for inline code): `if(window.location.hostname.indexOf('localhost') > -1){var url = "localhost:3000"} else { var url = window.location.hostname;}`

Comment: Ah I agree about the development more. Good call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go to the web root, use:

```
    window.location = '/';
```

You can also do that for any other page, such as:

```
    window.location = '/about/';
```

Starting your destination with '/' will change the page within your site / current domain.  So locally it'll be `localhost:3000/` but when live on a server, it will go to `http://www.mydomain.com/`

Also if you're looking for a better way to talk to rails urls from your application, you can use the routes variables.  In your console run `rake routes` and it'll list all the routes you have.  So the variable `root_path` will return `/` or whatever your root path may be set to within your app.

```
    <%= link_to "Home", root_path, target: '_blank' %>
```