# Window.location.href () and Window.open () in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, windows

What is the difference between `window.location.href ()` and `window.open()` methods in `JavaScript`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Window.location.href and Window.open () methods in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`window.location` is an **Object** and

`window.location.href` is its **property**

It tells you the **current URL location** of the browser

```
document.write(location.href);// will give location URL location of browser.
```

Setting the property will **redirect** the page.

`window.open()` is a **method** that you can pass a URL to that you want to **open in a new window**

E.g

`window.location.href = 'http://www.xyz.com'; //Will take you to xyz.`

`window.open('http://www.xyz.com'); //This will open xyz in a new window.`

Answer (score 5):

`window.location.href` changes the immediate window location.

`window.open()` will open a new window.