# Javascript window.location does not work

Tags: javascript

I have problem with this code that I can not understand. `Window.location` worked perfectly for me before but this time its not and I have no idea. When I access this direction manually - it works, but redirect does not work - just refreshes page. I have no clue what to do !

I've tried to **redirect** it to google or whatever but it still just refreshes.

```
$("#remove-form").on("submit", function(event) {
    usunRow();
});

function remove() {
    var id=document.getElementById("id").innerHTML;
    if (id != "ID"){
        $('#remove-modal').modal('show');
    } else $('#error-modal').modal('show');
}

function usunRow(){
    var id=document.getElementById("id").innerHTML;
    if (id != "ID"){
        window.location.href = "usun.php?id="+id;
        alert("usun.php?id="+id);
    } else $('#error-modal').modal('show');
}
```

here's all functions I am using for this

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634383/window-location-href-and-window-open-in-javascript

Comment: Where are you calling this `usunRow()` function ? provide that area code as well.

Comment: Is your alert (usun.php?id="+id) .. coming ?

Comment: @adi The alert is properly coming

Comment: Please check the console window to verify whether it is giving any error

Comment: @Ethris so my guess was right. You need to call `event.preventDefault()` before caliing `usunRow()` in the onsubmit callback. Otherwise the form is just getting submitted which reloads the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change** `window.location` to `window.location.href` this will changes the window location to a new location.

1. Make sure your `usunRow()` function call perfectly and there is no
   issue in your browser **console**.
2. **Also** make sure your `if` statement executes, may be your `if` statement is not executing that will be the reason that your page
   just refreshes not changing its location.

**UPDATED**

Add **return false**, because submitting a form will refresh your page `return false` will keep the page static and your `window.location.href` will redirect your page.

```
$("#remove-form").on("submit", function(event) {
            usunRow();
            return false;
});
```

Hope this solve your issue.

Comment: Make sure you `if` executes, are you getting an alert showing your new URL ?

Comment: change your `usun.php?id=+id` to `https://www.google.com` to make sure that there is not any problem with `unsun.php` just for checking purpose

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
window.location.href = "..."
```

It's not well documented but `window.location` actually is an object with non-standard behaviour, such as the reloading of the page and some non-readable or undocumented/quirky/browser-specific fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your console and type in `window.location`, you will understand why it doesn't work. It's an object containing many information about the current location:

```
Location {hash: "", search: "", pathname: "/questions/38870016/javascript-window-location-does-not-work", port: "", hostname: "stackoverflow.com"…}ancestorOrigins: DOMStringListassign: ()hash: ""host: "stackoverflow.com"hostname: "stackoverflow.com"href: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38870016/javascript-window-location-does-not-work"origin: "http://stackoverflow.com"pathname: "/questions/38870016/javascript-window-location-does-not-work"port: ""protocol: "http:"reload: reload()replace: ()search: ""toString: toString()valueOf: valueOf()__proto__: Location
```

Therefore, you try to replace this object with a string (your target url). The already mentioned property `href` of this location object is the one you need: `window.location.href = "new url"` or as short version `location.href = "new url"`

Comment: > Though Window.location is a read-only Location object, you can also assign a DOMString to it. This means that you can work with location as if it were a string in most cases: `location = 'http://www.example.com'` is a synonym of `location.href = 'http://www.example.com'`.

Answer (score 0):

How do you invoke usunRow() function?
Maybe you have click event on anchor without preventing it. That's why your page is refreshed. You need preventDefault() inside click event.

Comment: My bet is that `usunRow()` is triggered by an event listener on a link or button and there's a `preventDefault` call missing somewhere. This would ecplain the refresh.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using:

```
window.location.href = "";
```

Comment: The one who rejected the answer please tell me the reason?

Comment: Because window.location.href is not a function

Comment: Please read the question properly.The issue is with window.location

Comment: What? Your code was calling *window.location.href("")*. *href* is not a function, therefore you code would not have worked.