# Can I invoke a servlet URLwithout using AJAX

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets, jwplayer6

Can I invoke a URL,
 directly from javascript without using AJAX,on click of a play button, i am calling the playAlbumFromMediaUrl().

```
function playAlbumFromMediaUrl() {
    var trackMasterList = document.audioDetails.trackMasterIdList.value;

    var stringUrl = trackMasterList.split('::');


    for (var i = 0; i < stringUrl.length - 1; i++) {

        playlist[i] = {
            file: stringUrl[i],
            provider: "/teams/web/jwplayer/AkamaiAdvancedJWStreamProvider.swf"
        }

    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        jwplayerSetupForPlayAlbum();
    }, 1000);
}


function jwplayerSetupForPlayAlbum() {
    jwplayer('html5AudioPlayer').setup({
        playlist: [{
            file: "http://localhost:8080/servlet/MediaLibraryAccessServlet?trackMasterId=898035&isProtocol=rtmpe&assetFormat=MP448Full",
            provider: "/teams/web/jwplayer/AkamaiAdvancedJWStreamProvider.swf"
        }],
        width: 550,
        height: 30
    }).play();


}
```

Once the url is invoked,it calls the MediaLibraryAccess servlet class that returns a mp4 url, that can be played by the jwplayer.

I need to invoke the servlet url,without using AJAX.
For simplicity, i am not looping the playlist,instead i hard coded the servlet URL call in the jwplayer file attribute.

Can anyone help with this.

Comment: The trackMasterIdList contains a list of URL to be invoked.
Below is a sample list,

http://localhost:8080/servlet/MediaLibraryAccessServlet?trackMasterId=898035&isProtocol=rtmpe&assetFormat=MP448Full:: http://localhost:8080/servlet/MediaLibraryAccessServlet?trackMasterId=898037&isProtocol=rtmpe&assetFormat=MP448Full:: http://localhost:8080/servlet/MediaLibraryAccessServlet?trackMasterId=898039&isProtocol=rtmpe&assetFormat=MP448Full:: http://localhost:8080/servlet/MediaLibraryAccessServlet?trackMasterId=898041&isProtocol=rtmpe&assetFormat=MP448Full::

Comment: Looks like the same issue as [this past question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re

Comment: Dan,Looks like they are using jquery or Frames.I dont want to use them either.Is there a way to directly call the URL, so it invokes the servlet.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there are 4 basic ways to call a URL.

1. Direct POST/GET (normal clicking of a link)
2. Using frames
3. Using Ajax
4. Opening a pop-up window that will call the URL with one of the above methods.

Eliminating option 2-3 you are left with only option 1 witch I doubt that it will fill your needs. I think you should spend some times and make it work using options 2 or 3

UPDATE:

To use option 1 or 4 using javascript see [Window.location.href and Window.open () methods in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript)

In short for Option 1 you can use:

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; //Will take you to Google using GET.
```

Comment: Hi MaVRoScy, Can I use the first option to directly call the URL http://localhost:8080/servlet/MediaLibraryAccessServlet?trackMasterId=898035&isProtocol=rtmpe&assetFormat=MP448Full        from the javascript method.If so,how can I do it by POST or GET.

Comment: Thanks MaVRoSCy. I am able to hit the MediaLibraryAccessServlet class using window.location.href, but it should return a mp4 url, which I assign it to the file of the jwplayer. So,should i have to use  response.sendRedirect(html5playListUrl) OR out.write(html5playListUrl), to return from the servlet class.

Comment: both ways will do, the `response.sendRedirect` method though will cause the client make an extra call. If you can do it with the first method then it is recomended

Comment: I need to return only the StringUrl from the servlet class.So what should I use.I dont want to use response.sendRedirect() as it does another call.