# XSS attack vulnerability - Tweaking query using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, xss, cross-site

I have a situation where I need to exploit the xss vulnerability (For academic purpose - for an assignment)

So all I have to do it, add the javascript or jquery alongside URL and redirect it to some overpage which is there in the same server.

I am struck. I don't know why I am struggling to redirect with:

```
window.location = " redirect_To_This_URL"
```

Here are the specific details:

The actual URL:
example.com/xss/index.php?username=Administrator

This has a text input box where the user inputs his password and there is a button.(On successful password entry it takes to example.com/xss/login.php

But

I need to redirect it to `example.com/xss/fake.php`

Reference:
http://leakybox.cs.hut.fi/xss/index.php?username=Administrator

Comment: try `window.location.href`, also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript

Comment: Dunno why you need jQuery for this when you can just modify the script's action to go to fake.php in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

you need to close the "h1" tag before you put the script tag,the attack vector will look like

[Hover to see the attack vector](http://leakybox.cs.hut.fi/xss/index.php?username=Administrator%3C/h1%3E%3Cscript%3Ewindow.location=%27http://example.com/xss/fake.php%27%3C/script%3E)