# Javascript redirect on click

Tags: javascript, forms, button, onclick

```
<input name="btnCetak" type="submit" class="buttonPaging" style="width:200px;" value="Kemaskini Tarikh Serahan" onclick="document.pressed=this.value" />
<input name="export" type="submit" class="buttonPaging" value="Surat Akuan" onclick="document.pressed=this.value" />
```

The above is my 2 different buttons. The below code is my script function, `chkCheckBox`.

```
function chkCheckBox() 
{
    if(document.pressed=="Surat Akuan")
    {   
        var a=new Array();
        a=document.getElementsByName("chkCetak[]");
        var p=0;

        for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            if(a[i].checked)
                p=1;
        }

        if (p==0)
        {
            alert('Sila pilih Nama Pemohon.');
            return false;
        } 
        else 
        {
            var total=""
            for(var x=0; x< document.myForm.elements['chkCetak[]'].length;x++)
            {
                if(document.myForm.elements['chkCetak[]'][x].checked)
                    total +=document.myForm.elements['chkCetak[]'][x].value + "\n"
            }       

            if(total=="") 
            {

            } 
            else 
            { 
                document.myForm.submit();
                return true; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`chkCheckBox` works. My question is: How do I want to redirect to the other page when the "Surat Akuan" button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Just redirect?

```
location.href = "your link here";
```

you can find more info by google it, one of the link you can look on 
[Window.location.href and Window.open () methods in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript)

Comment: I have tried to put that statement in last else statement. but it not redirect to the page i want. i also have tried using window location..

Comment: what mean last statement? after total =="" if else statement? have you try to debug whether it meet the condition?