# How to move a page from one to another in HTML after Validation

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code

index.html

---

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="top"> New Record </div><br>
<form name="myForm"  onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
 <h5>Record name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"></h5>
 <div >
 <h5>Submitted Date <input id="sub" type="text" name="submited date" ></h5>
</div>
<div>
<h5>Started Date <input id="strtd" type="text" name="started date" ></h5>
</div>
 <div>
<h5> Record Type <select name="Record Type" id="options">
 <option value="Document">Documents</option>
 <option value="Pictures">Pictures</option>
<option value="Sounds">Sounds</option>
</select></h5>

</div>
 <div align="center">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Create">
<button id="cancel" type="button" onclick="ClearFields();">Reset</button>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and  script is here

```
  $(function(){
 var pickerOpts = {
  appendText: "",
  defaultDate: "+5",
  showOtherMonths: true,
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
 };  

  $("#strtd").datepicker({
   minDate: 0
  });

  $("#sub").datepicker({ 
  maxDate: new Date, 
 minDate: new Date(2007, 6, 12)
  });

  $('#strtd').focus(function() {
 this.blur();
  });
 $('#sub').focus(function() {
  this.blur();
  });

   });

  //form validation

  function validateForm() {
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
var y= document.forms["myForm"]["strtd"].value;
var z= document.forms["myForm"]["sub"].value;
if (x==null || x=="") {
    alert("First name must be filled out");
    return false;
 }

else if (y==null || y=="") {
    alert("Started Date must be filled out");
    return false;
  }

 else if (z==null || z=="") {
    alert("Submitted Date must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
  else {

  alert("New Reocrd Created");
 window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
  }
 }



function ClearFields() {
  document.getElementById("name").value="";
  document.getElementById("strtd").value="";
  document.getElementById("sub").value=""
}
```

In the above scripting code I have taken the example  `"window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";` just for checking and my requirement is to move the page to another html page

> eg:details.html

on clicking on create button.
Iam getting alert as "New Record Created" but not moving to  next page.
Hope  anyone of you helps :)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location.href` is not a method, it's a property that will tell you the current URL location of the browser. Setting the property to something different will redirect the page.

`window.open()` is a method that you can pass a URL to that you want to open in a new window. For example:

`window.location.href` example:

`window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';` //Will take you to Google.
`window.open()` example:

`window.open('http://www.google.com');` //This will open Google in a new window.

**Source : [SO Answer by James Hill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript)**

In case you want to open a local html page use:

`window.location('fullpath');`

Comment: Thanks for  your reply..The above window.open('http://www.google.com'); worked for me.But my requirement is to open a details.html file from index.html file. I have tried this window.open('/assets/www/details.html'); in place of window.open('http://www.google.com');.But didnt worked. Please assist me.Thanks in advance

Comment: need to give the full path :)
`window.open('file:///D:/Examples/file2.html')`

Comment: yes.I have tried by giving full path as window.open('file:///android_asset/www/details.html');.But not moving to next page.

Comment: What do you mean by "moving to next page"?

Comment: @user3132144 window.location('fullpath');

Comment: I mean when i clicked on create button it should navigate to next html page

Comment: Actually my details.html file is in assets/www/ folder .Iam giving the exact path as "file:///assets/www/details.html".Dont know where Iam strucking :(

Comment: you are missing the drive location like C:// or d://