# javascript error in button

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have a html button with a javascript to go to another page, but somehow the script doesn't work. Probably because I'm doing it wrong.
Please correct me .

```
    this.onclick = function(event)
{ 
location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
}
```

I should perhaps clarify that the button is generated by Birt Designer Pro. Its code is almost inaccessible, but this is from the xml:

```
<extended-item extensionName="HTMLButton" name="NewHTML Button" id="32"> <expression name="text" type="constant">klik</expression> </extended-item>
```

Comment: Add complete code. HTML and Javascript

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Might be a problem of `this` use. Make sure `this` is really your button. As @Tushar said, attach the rest of the code so we can help you.

Comment: Is your button like that `<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'">` ? No need of `this` because it's already used on a button

Comment: Obviously not @Hearner you can see `this.onclick` in the question source code... Also I agree with Tunshar, we need the full javascript source code for this, maybe display the html element(s) you have related to this.

Comment: uh... The button is generated by Birt Designer Pro. This from the xml file:<extended-item extensionName="HTMLButton" name="NewHTML Button" id="32">
                        <expression name="text" type="constant">klik</expression>
                    </extended-item>

Answer (score -1):

Just use

```
window.location="http://www.testpage.com";
```

to redirect from current to "http://www.testpage.com" in your javascript.

Comment: Just read this Post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript

Comment: This reference You've linked has nothing to do with this case. `open` is not  the same as `location.href`. Also Your solution does not solve the problem.