# html onclick redirect to another page but failed

Tags: html, redirect

I am using PHP and HTML. I have a link that should be redirected to a page  or refresh the page.

I have searched on Google the usage of `windows.location.href`, but failed.

The redirected html page is shown within the original html page. It seems a common problem but I do not know how to solve. Do you have any ideas on how to solve?

Comment: Can you write some of your code?

Comment: Seems like you dont neeed to use anything but <a href="#">.Simple use it. or expand you question and we can help further.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location = 'filename.php';
```

Try this one.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10948333)

Comment: He was using windows.location.href while it should be window.location so that's why I added this one.

Answer (score 0):

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript), `window.location.href` is a **property** that allows you to know the **current URL** location of the browser. Changing the value of the property will redirect the page.

```
`window.location.href` = 'http://www.nasa.gov'; //Will take the user to nasa.gov homepage.
```

Otherwise, as @Atilla Arda Açıkgöz stated in is comment an `<a href="#">` will do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I find that there exist xxx.html under the content area. When I remove xxx.html. It is working now.