# Open a URL always in the same new tab

Tags: javascript, tabs

How can I use `window.open` to open a link in a new tab?

Repeated calling should reload that same tab and not open a new one.

I've a button, when clicked should load a URL. Repeated click should reload in the same tab/window.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a name as the second parameter to `window.open`

As long as the tab with that name has not been closed, it will be reused.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
window.open('http://www.example.com','mywindow');
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/p26c2atz/

Answer (score 0):

In plain JS

```
<form>
  <input type="button" id="openWindow" value="Open Window" onclick="newTab()">
</form>
<script>
  function newTab() {
      var form = document.createElement("form");
      form.method = "GET";
      form.action = "http://www.example.com";
      form.target = "newWin";
      document.body.appendChild(form);
      form.submit();
  }

</script>
```

You can see it in action in https://jsfiddle.net/jprbj21u/

Other way will be:

```
<form>
  <input type="button" id="openWindow" value="Open Window" onclick="window.open('http://www.example.com','newWin')">
</form>
```

The link will open in a tab named "newWin".  As long as you open the same window any new URL will load on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do change target after focusout. I tested and its work.

Link

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a').focusout(function(e) {
    $(this).attr('target','_self');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.open(url,'someconstant',"width=600,height=700")`

Here on click event, there will be a new window opened with the instance named 'someconstant'. When you do a click again, the window will be opened again overwriting the previous window, as your instance is the same!