# page redirect is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#btnSubmit").live('click',function(){     
        var sum = '0';
        $("[id^=FormData_][id$=_c_data]").each(function(){

             var c_data = $(this).val();
              var required = $(this).attr("data-required");
              var label = $(this).attr("data-label");
              if(required == '1'){

                if(c_data == ""){
                    sum += '1';
                }
            }

        });

        if(sum == "0"){

        $("[id^=FormData_][id$=_c_data]").each(function(){
              var c_data = $(this).val();
            var admin = $(this).attr("data-admin");
            var form = $(this).attr("data-form");
            var component = $(this).attr("date-component");
            var unic = $(this).attr("data-unic");
             var user = $(this).attr("data-user");
              var url = "<?php echo  Yii::app()->createUrl('formdata/admin&id='.$form_id);?>";
            if(c_data == ""){

                var site_url = "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/formdata/deleteDetail' ); ?>";
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: site_url,
                    data: {new_value:c_data,admin:admin,form:form,component:component,unic:unic,user:user},
                    cache: false,
                    async: false,
                    success: function(response){

                    }
                });
            } else {

                var site_url = "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/formdata/updateDetailValue' ); ?>";
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: site_url,
                    data: {new_value:c_data,admin:admin,form:form,component:component,unic:unic,user:user},
                    cache: false,
                    async: false,
                    success: function(response){     
                    }
                });
            } 
        });
        window.location = "http://www.example.com";

        }else {
            if(sum != ""){

                bootbox.dialog({
                        message: 'Please Fill All Required Field !',
                        title: 'Alert',
                        buttons: {
                              main: {
                                label: 'OK',
                                className: 'blue'                        
                              }
                            }
                    });
                  return false;
                }  
        }
     });     
    });
</script>
```

in this script `window.location = "http://www.example.com"`; is not working.
But I check alert message it is working fine. why its not working in if condition.
I need to redirect page when each function was completed.
please any one help me:-((((((((((((((((((((((((((((

Comment: Try using `window.location.href = "http://example.com";`

Comment: 1. `window.location =....` need to be `window.location.replace(...)` or `window.location.href=....`. 2 May be your `if` condition always failed that's why it's not working (can't say until we see HTML part).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/506004/4248328

Comment: No.. my if condition is working fine and ajax post method is also working good....redirect only the pblm

Comment: I already try 1.window.location.href.. 2.window.location.replace(...)  3.$(location).attr("href",url) methods  .. its working good in inside of each function..but not working in outside of each function.

Comment: Please anyone help me

Comment: when do you want to redirect? on success of ajax?

Comment: Try to do `window.location.href` inside both the success callback of `if(c_data == "")` and its `else`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.,

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

This may work for you.

[Window.location.href and Window.open () methods in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not necessary, and `window.location.replace(url)` will best simulate an HTTP redirect.

still you want to do this with jQuery use this `$(location).attr('href', 'url')`

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correct, you want to redirect the user when all your `ajax` requests, within your `each` function, are completed. For this, you can create an `array` that will hold the success status of each `ajax` request, and depending on this `array` you may do your redirection task.

Add below few snippets to your existing code:

1. In your `#btnSubmit` `click` function (Though, I recommend you use `.on()` delegation method)

   ```
   var ajax_succ_arr = []; // success status container
   var this_ajax_succ = false; // flag
   ```
2. In you `success` function of both `ajax` calls (within your `each` function).

   ```
       if(c_data == ""){
           ...
           jQuery.ajax({
               ...
               success: function(response){
                 if(response == "1"){
                   this_ajax_succ = true; // set true if required response is received
                 }
               }
           });
           ajax_succ_arr.push(this_ajax_succ); // push it to the success array
        } else {
            ...
           jQuery.ajax({
               ...
               success: function(response){
                 if(response == "1"){
                   this_ajax_succ = true; // set true if required response is received
                 }
               }
           });
           ajax_succ_arr.push(this_ajax_succ); // push it to the success array
       }
   ```
3. And finally your redirection. Put this just after `each` function ends.

   ```
   if(ajax_succ_arr.indexOf(false)<0){ // if all statuses are ok
     window.location="http://www.example.com";
   }
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-))))))))))