# JavaScript page refresh issue

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to handle page refresh in JavaScript ? After browser close button is clicked my application should be logged out and after clicking on browser back button application should be logged out also.

Comment: perhaps the onbeforeunload event (not likely though), or sendBeacon on modern browsers could help

Comment: what if user's browser has javascript disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet by clicking run and reload or backwards in your browser.

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  //call your function
  return "Attention Reload"
};
```

Have a look at [this eventHandler](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Answer (score 0):

Try This Answer
[This answer will help you out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser)

Also this only shows how to access the back button functionality in **cross browser**, However in the scope of those functions, 
You can **destroy your token** or whatever to logout or you can directly use **window.location.href**, description of the same is given in [Window.location.href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript)

Hope that helps, Also if this does not solve specify more details in question that how are you logging out,

Thanks & Regards

Shohil Sethia