# react-redux redirect to other page after login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

`action.js`:

```
export const login = creds => {
    console.log(`${url}/login`);
    const requestOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: creds
    };

    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_REQUEST });
        function timer() {
            return fetch(`${url}/login`, requestOptions).then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    console.log(response);
                    return response.json().then(json => {
                        var error = new Error(json.message);
                        error.response = response;
                        throw error;
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log("3");
                    return response.json();
                }
            }).then(user => {
                if (user.message === "ok") {
                    localStorage.setItem("token", user.token);
                    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: user.token });
                    window.location.href = `${app}/dashboard`;
                } else {
                    const error = user.message;
                    throw new Error(error);
                }
            }).catch(function(error) {
                dispatch(loginError(error));
            });
        }
        setTimeout(timer, 5000)
    }
};
```

I am unable to redirect in a single-page manner to my dashboard, I searched a lot but I didn't get anything useful. I am using React Router v4. Can you please suggest whether I am doing this user login with JWT the right way or not.

Comment: I am not familiar with react, but I think  it might be a misunderstanding of window.location.href, If you choose to use window.location.href, you should specify the whole path, so for instance maybe window.location.href = http://localhost:5000/${app}/dashboard. I think this is quite a nice source, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript

Answer (score 10, accepted):

create a your own `history` in `history.js` file using this [history library](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history).

```
//history.js
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

const history = createHistory()

export default history
```

Supply it to your router:

```
<Router history = {history}>.....</Router>
```

Then you can use this `history` object to redirect from anywhere. In your action:

```
import history from './history'
history.push(`${app}/dashboard`)
```

Comment: hey,it worked very well, but i have create a separate function for authentication for route,but its seems it is now working,here is link for code https://gist.github.com/5c6c14e2d2503b4d22872b983bccd978 , is this a proper approach?

Comment: What is this `${app}` of which you speak?

Comment: or you can just pass the history props to login action.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can add `react-router-redux` which will conveniently add all routing info to the Redux state, but also you can use `push` from `react-router-redux` by:

   ```
   dispatch(push('/dashboard'))
   ```

   You can access it by

   ```
   import { push } from 'react-router-redux'
   ```
2. I think you are not doing anything wrong with JWT. I would abstract your `fetch` call with the helper function. I assume you need to add your access token to all future requests after authorization, and using helper function you can do it easier and keep you code cleaner.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but i tried react-router-redux,but was not working

Comment: You need to:
1. `import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';`
2. `import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';`
3. `import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';`
4. `const store = createStore([YOUR ROOT REDUCER], applyMiddleware(routerMiddleware(browserHistory),));` // You might need to compose middleware if you are using others.
5. `const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);`
6. `<BrowserRouter><Router history={history}>`

It's a bit of setup, but it worth it. Let me know if you need my help with it.

Comment: Btw, after all above you can use `browserHistory` from `react-router` in your component by: `browserHistory.push('/login')`. It might be useful to redirect user back to login if anonymous needs to access page which is available for authenticated users only.

Comment: ok,thanks if i need help i will let you know,but using history api is also easy and fast solution,right?

Comment: Sure it is. If you need to achieve just simple redirect, history api is probably the best option.

Answer (score 2):

`window.location.href` will hit your server and you'll loose all the benefits of a single page application, you should use a client side routing instead with the history object

In this scenario a good solution could be pass a callback from the component that triggers the first dispatch containing a history.push to the new state

e.g.

Assuming that inside your component props you have access to history

```
login(body, () => {
  this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
})
```

then in place of `window.location.href = ${app}/dashboard` you invoke the callback