# login with facebook javascript sdk redirection is not working

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

Here i am doing **login with facebook**,functionalities working fine but after logged i want to redirect to some URl ,don't how to redirect, i searched but i am not getting the solution.`login with facebook` documentation i found from [HERE](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/#example).I tried lot i am not able find a solution,if any one know means please update my answer.i check in that documentation also but not there in that documentation

> My Working code

```
    // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
   // console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    //console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into your app or we are unable to tell.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '1990039811315283',
      cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                          // the session
      xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
      version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
    });

    // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
    // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
    // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
    // the callback you provide.  They can be:
    //
    // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
    // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
    // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
    //    your app or not.
    //
    // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,email'}, function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      /* document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!'; */
        //console.log(response.email);

        //window.location.href = "fb_login.php";
          $.ajax({
            url:'admin/rest/getEvents',
            type:'POST',
            //data:JSON.stringify(event_date),
            success:function(response){


            },
        }); 


    });
  }
```

Comment: Does `statusChangeCallback` get called and can you see that the person has logged in? If so, `window.location.href` will allow you to go to a new page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript

Comment: uncomment the line that does the redirect and it should work.. assuming that page exists.. `window.location.href = "fb_login.php";`

Comment: @ Occam's Razor, because of this condition' if (response.status === 'connected')',suppose i am uncomment this line **window.location.href = "fb_login.php"** means again and again redirection is happening,for me redirection should happen single time only

Comment: @ Occam's Razor, yor are getting my question,suppose first time login means it will redirect `single` time suppose already logged in means again and again redirection is happening