# window.open vs window.location.href

Tags: javascript, html

How do I decide whether to open my local web page window with `window.open` or `window.location.href`?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Window.location.href and Window.open () methods in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if window.opener == null

// open by window.location.href

else

// open by window.open

Answer (score 1):

Simply,

`window.open()` will open a new window for your passing URL in side the parentheses.

`window.location.href` will redirect you to the passing URL with in the same window.

Comment: I mean use jQuery or javascript in the local Web Page. Can you have a good idea? Thank you.

Comment: According to my knowledge I think it's better to use javascript with in a separate file in your project folder. But anyways it depends on your taste :)

Comment: You can use `window.open('<URL>', '_self')` to open a url in the same tab https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open