# How to pass variables from PHP to Javascript redirect

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I've put together this short little code that should randomly pick a url from "url.txt" and then redirect it through a javascript redirect. For whatever reason I can't get it to work. I'm aware of how to get it to work with other forms of redirection including meta refresh and php header, however I would like to know how to do with with javascript redirection.

```
<?php 
   $loadlist = explode("\n", file_get_contents('urls.txt'));
   $rand = rand(0,count($loadlist)-1);
   $picked = $loadlist[$rand];
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  window.location.href = '<?php echo $picked ?>'
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: missing `;` - both in js and php - typo. Possible duplicate [window.location.href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript)

Comment: Both `;` are optional in this case (it's a matter of preference, though not having them in JS might not work in older browsers?). @bakingsoda This code should work, are you sure your redirect URL is valid/correct? Check the source.

Comment: I would recommend always using the semi-colon, but it is optional in this case.

Comment: most likely what's happening is.. you mention `url.txt`, but you're using `urls.txt`, prob got error reporting off so the array is empty and looking for `0` or `-1` index in an empty array. `$picked` then is obviously empty

Comment: it has nothing to do with semi-colons; but is it! ;p

Comment: `;` is optional in JS. The final `;` is optional in PHP when the closing tag is on the same line as the last statement. What is your PHP script outputting? Is the redirect blocked by the browser? Browsers sometimes block JS redirects to protect against potentially malicious scripts.

Comment: does url located outside your web site?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
   $loadlist = explode("\n", file_get_contents('urls.txt'));
   $rand = rand(0,count($loadlist)-1);
   $picked = $loadlist[$rand];
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  window.location.replace("<?php echo $picked ?>");
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Try this

Comment: With this code I see that a url is echoed out when I view source. However, no redirect occurs and I just get a blank screen.

Comment: Still the missing semicolon on end of `echo` statement

Comment: @GetSet No need for a `;` before `?>` (some prefer to have it, but it's optional).