# Firefox WebExtension API: how to go to url in active tab?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I just started with making a firefox (web)extension / addon.
It is pretty awesome. But cannot really find it how to go to an url in the active tab.
When I do `document.open('https://www.github.com','', 'noopener=true');` it will open a new popup. But it would be nice to go another link in the same tab.

Thanks :),

Daan

Comment: maybe `location.href` it is what are you looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript

Comment: Are you trying to do this from a content script or a script in the background context? Are you doing it from a popup? What permissions have you defined?

Answer (score 0):

Not the active tab but anyway :)

document.location.href = "https://www.gitlab.com";