# Redirect to ExternalLogin Identity page from Angular

Tags: angular, authentication, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity

I have an external login: Active Directory and i want to redirect user from angular home page to identity external login like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['authentication/login']);
```

Is there any way to do something like this?

```
this.router.navigate(['authentication/external-login']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The router is for internal navigation (i.e. routes that are registered for the application).

For external routes, I would use the `window` object. Learn more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7077814/7365461).