# Javascript _self tag not working on search bar

Tags: javascript, search

Hey guys still still trying to get this to work I want the pages to open in the same window rather than opening a new window?? any suggestions without changing my entire code

```js
function openPage() {
        var x = document.getElementById("search").value;
             x = x.replace(/\b\w/g, (firstLetter) => firstLetter.toUpperCase());

            if (x === "Aaron Carter") { 
                  window.open("files/aaroncarter.html";
            }

            if (x === "Albert Einstein") {
                window.open ("files/alberteinstein.html");
            }
            
             else {
                window.open ("files/error.html" , "_self")
            }
            
            }
```

```html
 <form action="" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="search" id="search" autocomplete="off" onchange="openPage()"  class="form-control rounded-pill rounded-end-0 border-0 ps-4" placeholder="Search... e.g. Stan Laurel">
                  <button type="button" id="button" onclick="openPage()" value="Chercher" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill rounded-start-0 shadow-none">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

Comment: Unless it's your intention to always show the error page unless "Aaron Carter" is the regEx modified version of the search term, you want to change the 2nd `if` to an `else if` - just like the answer which appeared as I was typing this suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using window.open use window.location.href

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript#:%7E:text=window.open%20()%20will%20open,URL%20in%20your%20current%20window.) is related to your question.

```js
function openPage(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var x = document.getElementById("search").value;
  x = x.replace(/\b\w/g, (firstLetter) => firstLetter.toUpperCase());

  if (x === "Aaron Carter") {
    window.location.href = "files/aaroncarter.html";
  } else if (x === "Albert Einstein") {
    window.location.href = "files/alberteinstein.html";
  } else {
    window.location.href = "files/error.html";
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="search" id="search" autocomplete="off" class="form-control rounded-pill rounded-end-0 border-0 ps-4" placeholder="Search... e.g. Stan Laurel">
    <button type="submit" id="button" onclick="openPage(event)" value="Chercher" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill rounded-start-0 shadow-none">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer which was already posted before yours?

Comment: It's not. I did not see your answer before posting mine. It seems we both worked on it and arrived at the same solution independently.

Answer (score 2):

The `target` parameter to `window.open` should reference an existing named window. `_self` means the current window and since `window.open()` would normally open a new window, `_self` points to that newly opened window. You could specify a `name` for the original window and then reference that.

But, the simplest solution is don't use `window.open()` and just change the [`window.location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) to the desired URL.

```
 location.href = "files/error.html";
```